# How do I allow contributors to make branches, but not commit to main in an organization?

Tags: github, github-organizations

Context: Me and my colleagues, are working on a college project. Some of them are new to git, github, and react. I created a github organization, thinking it would be easy to manage.

I want to divide people into 2 roles, **reviewers** and **contributors** (juniors) such that **contributors** will not have write permission to the main branch, but can create new feature branches in the same repo and will have to get PR approvals from **reviewers** to merge to main. I'm aware of teams and branch protection rules, but I'm not sure what the correct setup is. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could look into protecting the main branch, see [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) for more.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I did try it before asking this question, I set up a new global git account without write permission, on my windows machine (I use wsl-ubuntu for my main). But when I tried committing, pushes were being accepted to main. I think this has to do something with how git handles credentials. If you have already authorized it with your main in the past, pushes which are normally rejected will get accepted because of the main account. I had to ask someone else to test this on their PC. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Git*Hub* decides who *you* are (and hence your access permissions) depending on how you connect to GitHub. Git itself has no access control at all; this is all GitHub add-ons. If you connect to GitHub with ssh, GitHub will use the public key you provide (use `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to see who they decide you are). If you connect to GitHub with https, they will ask for a user name and token, and use the user name you give them.